# Употребление метатэгов Keywords

Tags: html

Здравствуйте.

У меня такой вопрос по метатегу Keywords: говорят, что слова не должны повторяться, а если речь идет о привязке к конкретному городу, например, нужно, чтобы искало по "магазины в Москве", "товары в Москве", "предприятия Москвы" и тд., можно ли в этом случае обойтись простым указанием "Москва, магазины, товары, предприятия" или же надо будет перечислять как выше написано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я помню, к ключевых словах указываются именно слова. Бессвязные, так сказать. Те, которые наиболее часто встречаются в тексте страницы, по которым будут искать.
А описание (description) в соответствующем мета-теге. Там как-раз можно написать "магазины в Москве", "товары в Москве", "предприятия Москвы". Но лучше нечто наподобие "Наиболее актуальный список товаров, предприятий и магазинов в Москве".

Keywords чисто для поисковиков. 
Description для посетителей сайта.(показывается при поиске сайта в поисковике, под названием сайта)